# Babel register different presets for different extensions

Tags: babeljs, flowtype, babel-register

If I'm using babel-register, can I have certain presets map to certain extenions? Or do all presets run all extensions.

For example, this works:

```
require('babel-register')({
    presets: ["react", "es2015", "flow"],
    extensions: [".jsx", ".js"]
});
```

But what I really want is something like this:

```
require('babel-register')(
    {
        presets: ["react", "es2015"],
        extensions: [".jsx"]
    },
    {
        presets: ["flow"],
        extensions: [".js"]
    }
);
```

I've looked in the docs and tried some permutations of this, but I haven't had any luck. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but I also can't think of any good reason to do it. Why do you want to use different presets for different extensions? `babel-register` is meant to transform all code such that it can be run. I'd want to have all presets applied to all files, because if a feature is used in a file, it needs to be transpiled, and if it isn't, the preset won't have any effect.

Comment: @MichaelJungo If I'm using a modern version of Node, it seems wasteful to unnecessarily transpile es2015 features in .js files when all I need are flow types removed.

Comment: That would mean that you don't need it at all. When you use `babel-register` you'll run all the code under the same environment, I don't see why they should be treated differently. If you don't want to transpile any feature that is supported by the current version, you should use [`babel-preset-env`](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env) with [`"node": "current"`](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env#target-latest-node-via-node-true-or-node-current) instead of `babel-preset-es2015`. `env` is officially recommended over `es2015` and without a target it covers everything of it.

Comment: @MichaelJungo Yup, I get it, that makes sense. I was thrown off a bit by React's insistence on using es2015. Thanks for the help. I used `require('babel-register')({
 presets: [["env", {
  "targets": {
   "node": "current"
  }
 }], "react", "flow"],
 extensions: [".jsx", ".js"]
});`

If you put an official answer, I would select it.